# C - Cannot iterate through second string onward

Tags: c

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

Problem statement:
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/good-or-bad-string/0

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int is_vowel(char a) {
    if(a==97||a==101||a==105||a==111||a==117){
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
int main() {
    //code
    int t,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        char str[100];
        scanf("%s",str);
        printf("%s",str);
        int c_cnsnt=0;
        int c_vwl=0;
        int g_b=1;//suppose good
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(str);j++){
            //("%c",str[j]);
            int num=is_vowel(str[j]);
            printf("Debug %c %d %d\n",str[j],num,strlen(str));
            if(is_vowel(str[j])) {
                c_vwl++;
            }
            else { c_cnsnt++;}
            if(c_vwl==c_cnsnt){
                c_cnsnt=0;
                c_vwl=0; 
            }
            else {
                if(c_vwl>5||c_cnsnt>=3){
                    g_b=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        printf("%d\n",g_b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample

Input:

```
2
aeioup??
bcdaeiou??
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

My solution link:

https://code.hackerearth.com/9bca55K

Why does the for loop not work for the 2nd string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You have to clear the the consonant and vowel counts after increment the other (e.g `{c_vwl++;c_cnsnt=0;}`), not when they are equal, and always tests your BAD condition.

I will not give you a sample code. Good luck

Comment: I have improved my code and now it is giving correct ans for first tc but loop is not iterating over second string why?

Comment: please see https://code.hackerearth.com/9bca55K

Comment: Made it!! Thanks

Comment: @confused If you'd like, do edit your question to include the working solution you came up with.